# Can the United Kingdom Legislature legislate anything it wants?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, government, sovereignty

This question arises from an answer to a question [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/47477/28397) regarding Parliamentary Sovereignty. If the UK Parliament was to legislate for something, assuming it didn't violate international treaties etc., is there anything that could stop that becoming law?

So for example Parliament was to pass a bill that said:

> On a Tuesday it is illegal to wear shoes on roads that have more than
>   two vowels in their name.

Now obviously mass public outcry could pretty quickly encourage their representatives to change their mind, and likely a new party "Footware Freedom Party" would probably be started up pretty quickly.

But are there any outside forces that could prevent this from becoming law, or overturn the bill?

*I've deliberately made the bill insanely silly to try to avoid debates over it, I am more interested in the workings of Parliamentary Sovereignty*

Comment: Are you asking about the UK specifically? I don't really see why an uncodified constitution has anything to do with it.

Comment: In the US, one of the earliest Supreme Court cases established that the courts can overturn parts of a law which violate the Constitution.  The question appears to basically be whether Judicial Review can exist in a country with no founding document that would pre-empt the Legislature.

Comment: Yes, @IllusiveBrian, this is essentially what I am asking.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica Maybe the UK is the best example for this being one of the first Pariamentary Democracies and also having said uncodifed constitution. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncodified_constitution)

Comment: @PandaPops I think having a specific country in your question is easier. If you're just talking about a hypothetical country with an uncodified constitution then the answer may depend on what's in the legal instruments, the customs or the [*constitutional statutes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoburn_v_Sunderland_City_Council) of such a country. So the general question may be rather broad whereas the specific question might be easily answerable based on precedent and court rulings.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica I will edit the question to specify the uk, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Something something royal assent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_assent

Comment: Royal assent is basically a formality for any Bill that passes through both houses and passes all it’s readings.

Comment: @PandaPops it's a formality right up to when it isn't.

Comment: @Caleth The Queens role as head of state is purely ceremonial, she acts on the advice of here government, if she was to deny royal assent it would cause a constitutional crisis.

Comment: @PandaPops The Queen has hinted there are imaginable circumstances where she would prefer a constitutional crisis to passing a particular law

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the UK, there is the concept of Primary and Secondary legislation - primary legislation consists of the acts passed by Parliament, while secondary legislation consists of the regulations put in place by executive agencies and regulatory bodies that implement primary legislation.

Under the UKs doctrine of Parliamentary Sovereignty, not even the Supreme Court can overturn Primary legislation - it can overturn Secondary legislation where it is deemed to breach the Primary legislation that enables it.

The Supreme Court can make a declaration of incompatibility of Primary legislation under Section 4 of the Human Rights Act 1998 if it considers the legislation to be incompatible with something issued either under that act or the European Convention on Human Rights, and that normally leads it to be re-examined by Parliament.

The Supreme Court can also suggest that primary legislation be re-examined by Parliament should it consider it to be dangerous, but would still need to implement the legislation as it stands.

In short, no - once passed by Parliament, an Act becomes law and only ceases to be law once a repealing Act is passed.  There are many cases in the UK where a Judge has commented on the absurdity of a law but noted that he has to implement it as it stood.

Comment: Citations to follow once I’m back on something with a sane keyboard and copy and paste system.